# Unserialize an xml fragment as a string

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have an xml file having the following structure

```
<claims id="claims01" lang="en">
    <claim id="c-en-01-0001" num="0001">
        <claim-text>bla bla:
            <claim-text>- one,</claim-text>
            <claim-text>- two,</claim-text>
            and also:
            <claim-text>- three,</claim-text>
            <claim-text>- four,</claim-text>
            <claim-text>- five.</claim-text>
        </claim-text>
    </claim>
    <!-- multiple claim -->
</claims>
```

I try to unserialize the claims set by using an XmlSerializer with the following classes:

```
public class EPPDClaims {
    [XmlAttribute("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("lang")]
    public string Lang { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("claim")]
    public List<EPPDClaim> Claims { get; set; }
}

public class EPPDClaim {
    [XmlAttribute("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("num")]
    public int Number { get; set; }

    [XmlAnyElement("claim-text")]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

In the EPPDClaim.Text I wish to get

```
"<claim-text>bla bla:<claim-text>- one,</claim-text><claim-text>- two,</claim-text>and also:<claim-text>- three,</claim-text><claim-text>- four,</claim-text><claim-text>- five.</claim-text>&lt;/claim-text>"
```

I try with :

- XmlElement("claim-text")
- XmlText()
- XmlAnyElement("claim-text")

but nothing do.

Is there a simple way to handle this unserialization with XmlSerializer or must I go to an IXmlSerializable implementation for the Text property ?

for information the DTD:

```
<!ELEMENT claim-text  (#PCDATA | claim-text | claim-ref | b | i | u | o | sup | sub | 
           smallcaps | br | pre | crossref | figref | img | chemistry | maths | 
           tables)* >
```

Comment: for the xml innertext I usually use : [XmlText]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this: (XmlAnyElement with the XmlNode type)

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute("claims", Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public class EPPDClaims
{
    [XmlAttribute("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("lang")]
    public string Lang { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("claim")]
    public List<EPPDClaim> Claims { get; set; }
}

public class EPPDClaim
{
    [XmlAttribute("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("num")]
    public int Number { get; set; }
    [XmlAnyElement("claim-text")]
    public XmlNode Text { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(EPPDClaims));
        var obj = (EPPDClaims)serializer.Deserialize(System.IO.File.OpenRead("test.xml"));
        string s = obj.Claims.First().Text.InnerXml;
    }
}
```

After the deserialization, the content of the string s is:

```
bla bla:
<claim-text>- one,</claim-text><claim-text>- two,</claim-text>
and also:
<claim-text>- three,</claim-text><claim-text>- four,</claim-text><claim-text>- five.</claim-text>
```